# landing page get blank after docker-conterized angular app

Tags: angular, docker, containers

inside container, I have see the js file, cat index.html you see those js files as well,
[image: container]

below is landing page
[image: landingpage]

Comment: if I append any string after localhost:5001, like localhost:5001/abc, it will navigate to not found page I created, means apps is containerized, but landing page isnt properly displayed